# How to get documents where referenced document has some field in mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First of all i'm totally new to MongoD and i tried searching a lot, didn't find any solution or maybe i was searching wrong.
Let's say i have following documents

```
const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});
```

I can query persons like this with their stories

```
const persons = await Person.find().populate('stories');
```

I need to query persons which have stories from a specific author

```
const persons = await Person.find({"stories.author":"someobjectid"}).populate('stories');

// This didn't work*/
```

Is it possible to query like this Or do i need to change person schema

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find anything by ObjectId then you have to use this syntax:

```
const persons = await Person.find({"stories.author":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(author_id)}).populate('stories');//<==== Replace author_id with your actual variable.
```